# Characteristic polynomial of linear operator and matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Does the characteristic polynomial of a linear operator always equal to the characteristic polynomial of its representation under some basis $\mathcal{B}$?
That is $c_{\tau}(x) = c_{[\tau]_{\mathcal{B}}}(x)$?

Another question is why the characteristic polynomial of a symmetric linear operator may have complex root? (we know symmetric matrix always has real eigenvalues.) Is there some example?

The characteristic polynomial is defined by product of elementary divisor for $\tau$ .

The symmetric operator means $(\tau v,w) = (v,\tau w)$ that is adjoint for real bilinear form.

$[\tau]_{\mathcal{B}}$ is the matrix that columns are coordinate of $\tau(b_i)$ under basis $\mathcal{B}$

Comment: The answer to your first question is yes (by any reasonable definition), but for a proof you would have to provide the definition for the "characteristic polynomial of an operator" that you are working with

Comment: The answer to your second question again depends on what your definition is.  What exactly is a "symmetric linear operator" in this context?

Comment: The key problem here is how to use the elementary divisor definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: the characteristic polynomial of a linear operator always equal to the characteristic polynomial of its representation under any choice basis $\mathcal B$.   The fact that this is so is a direct consequence of the structure theorem for PIDs (which presumably you have seen if you are doing anything with "elementary divisors").  In particular, there is a direct correspondence between elementary divisors of an operator and elementary divisors of the associated matrix.

For a more thorough discussion, see [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_normal_form#General_case_and_theory).

Regarding your second question: if our vector space is over the field $\Bbb R$ and the bilinear form is [positive definite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_quadratic_form), then "symmetric operators" will correspond to "symmetric (real) matrices", which means that the spectral theorem applies and the roots of the characteristic polynomial must be real.  For other bilinear forms, we can make no such guarantee.

An example of a "symmetric" operator that fails to have real eigenvalues.  Consider the bilinear form over $\Bbb R^2$ given by
$$
(x,y) = x_1y_2 + x_2 y_1.
$$
Relative to this bilinear form, we find that the operator $x \mapsto Ax$ where
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0}
$$
is "symmetric", but has no real eigenvalues.

Comment: Do you mean under hermitian form it may have complex root? can you provide an example for this case? I was a bit confused about it. By the way, can you provide some reference book that relevant to this topic?

Comment: @yi_li A Hermitian form is not a bilinear form, so no I was not talking about that.  As far as the structure theorem and all that go I would recommend Dummit and Foote.  What book are you working out of?  Your combination of definitions is very strange

Comment: I didn't read the book carefully,I was reading GTM advanced linear algebra. Can you give an example that symmetric operator may have complex root.

Comment: @yi_li Is that the textbook by Roman?  In any case I'll add that example to the answer.

Comment: I should also mention that Hoffman and Kunze is a good reference.  They have a chapter on the rational canonical form, which is what it looks like you're interested in.

Comment: yeah is that book, thank you for your help.